# Pass selected item id as value to different model. wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a list view that displays a given number of students. And I also have a button named "add parent" that shows a form for adding a selected students' parent.

What I want is to pass *selected student id* as the student id *to the parent view model*. Parent model has a relationship to student model. If a student is selected their student id is shown in a textblock that binds to parent view model student id value.

Some code would really be helpful.

Comment: Do you use any mvvm framework?

Comment: Yes mvvm light. Galasoft

Comment: Can you post some code? I dont know how you navigate to parent view, but I think you could pass selected student id, to the command of the button, and then use it when you navigate to the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=listViewName, Path=SelectedItem.ID}"/>
```

Then you don't have to worry about handling the selected item in the ViewModel.

Comment: How would i pass selecteditem.id value as StudentID value to parent/view model.

Comment: Are you binding the SelectedItem of the ListView to a property in your ViewModel?

Comment: Yes that's what i am doing.

Comment: You can implement a Command on your parent view model for your button which will send the selected item of the list as a command parameter. [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM)